# Why do sandboxing sites employ sandboxing which interferes with CSS manipulation through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

While searching the web for a way to create CSS classes on the fly using JavaScript and modifying them later on, I stumbled upon [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information#Modify_a_stylesheet_rule)(1) example on the mozilla web docs.

The JavaScript code should change the background color of the body element defined as red:

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to blue:

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

However in the [iframe they embedded below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information#frame_Modify_a_stylesheet_rule) this does not seem to work.

The same code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97urc683/) however does work as intended.

Why does it work *sometimes* and sometimes not? And is there a way to get this to work consistently?

---

1:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Modifying a stylesheet rule with CSSOM</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
            stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The stylesheet declaration for the body's background color is modified via JavaScript.
    </body>
</html>
```

---

*Note: The above described behavior does show up using Firefox as well as Google Chrome.*

Comment: All the sandboxing sites *do* employ sandboxing, which sometimes interferes with how the code inside it works, since it's not *actually* running on a page now. Depends on how the site actually does the sandboxing. In particular, it seems like CodePen is wrong - it has the HTML for the entire page with `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` but it transfers all that content that into `<body>` only stripping away some tags.

Comment: Check the browser console, it will tell you what is preventing the iframe version from working. And on codepen, the whole HTML for a complete document is placed into the HTML input field - but that should contain the contents of body only. Result is that the stylesheets is down in the body, and the code tries to manipulate the first rule in `<style class="cp-pen-styles"></style>` instead, which was automatically inserted by codepen, but doesn’t contain _any_ rules.

Comment: please update your links and share your code here directly

Comment: @VLAZ Thank for this answer, I guess I should change the question to "Why do sandboxing sites employ sandboxing which interferes with how the code inside it works?"

Comment: @NicolasBrauer an even more precise wording would be "*Why do sandboxing sites employ sandboxing which interferes with *this particular* code works?*". The problem is that generally sandboxing shouldn't interfere but...it's still a sandbox and should come with some limitations. The ones chosen interfere with this functionality but might work for 99.9% of all cases in general. Another site might work for *this* code but only cover 80% of all functionality due to other restrictions.

Comment: @NicolasBrauer It does not interfare with your code.  The problem is that you are selecting the wrong stylesheet. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both the iframe and the codepen version include additional stylesheets, so that `document.styleSheets[0]` no longer references the right stylesheet.

But the issue is neither JS nor CSS. It is referencing the stylesheet like this.

Imagine using this approach when in your code: instead of using classes and IDs, you'd have to rely on

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[7];
var closeButton = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[12];
```

I dare you to build a page like this. You'd be hesitant to change anything in fear of breaking everything.

Answer (score 1):

#### You are not selecting the right `stylesheet`.

You are selecting the first `stylesheet` whose first `cssRule` does not have `backgroundColor`. A page may have more than one `stylesheets`.

It works if you are using the same code in a simple HTML file that does not have any other stylesheet.

If should also work should you select a stylesheet that has the same `cssRule` as in your code.

---

CodePen uses an `iframe` which sandboxes your code. And it has multiple `stylesheet`s. Therefore, It does not work.

---

Alternatively, you can set an `id` or a `className` on the current `stylehseet`, loop through all of the stylesheets, and change background of the one that matches the id or the className depending on which one of the selectors you use.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Modifying a stylesheet rule with CSSOM</title>
  <style type="text/css" id="unique-stylseeht">
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBackground(id, color) {
      for (let sheet of document.styleSheets) {
        if (sheet.ownerNode.id === id) {
          sheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
      }
    }

    changeBackground('unique-stylseeht', 'blue')

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  The stylesheet declaration for the body's background color is modified via JavaScript.
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On that page, I get this console error:

"Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

It looks like increased security measures in modern browsers have hindered communication across the iFrame boundary and rendered the code nonfunctional.

Comment: This is not about any cross-frame communication; the stylesheet URL simply returns a 404. (And since the Content-Type of the returned 404 document is text/html, it eventually results in this error message.)